# Add new row and calculate seperate value from html table

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML table  have to add new row and change row to sale various product. my problem is that when i add new row and input square feet then calculation properly output pieces . If i input pieces then properly output square feet. If i do that one after one then no problem but if i go back at  first row and change square feet or pieces. all value are changed. please help me any one .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var category = $("#grade_id").val();
    //alert(category)
    if (category == '') {
      alert('Please Select Grade');
    } else {
      addNewRow();
    }
  })

  function addNewRow() {
    /* 
     var grade = $("#grade_id").val();
     //alert(grade)
     $.ajax({
      url :"{{ route('sale.getBrands')}}",
      method : "GET",
      data : {grade:grade},
      success : function(data){
       //alert(data)
       $("#invoice_item").append(data);
       var n = 0;
       $(".number").each(function(){
        $(this).html(++n);
       })
      }
     })*/
    $("#invoice_item").append('<tr><td><select class="form-control pid" name="" id="grade_id"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">Product Code - 1001</option><option value="2">Product Code - 1002</option><option value="3">Product Code - 1003</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control stock" value="250"></td><td><input type="text" name="square_feet" class="form-control square_feet" ></td><td><input type="text" name="prices" class="form-control pices"></td><td><input type="text" name="sale_price" class="form-control sale_price"></td><td>BDT:<span class="amt">0</span></td></tr>');
  }
  /* for remove row-*/
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    $("#invoice_item").children("tr:last").remove();
  })

  $("#invoice_item").delegate(".pid", "change", function() {
    var pid = $(this).val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    //alert(pid)
    $(".overlay").show();

    $('.price').keyup(function() {
      tr.find(".amt").html(tr.find(".qty").val() * tr.find(".price").val());
    })

    $('.square_feet').keyup(function() {
      //alert('ok')
      var order_square_feet = $(this).val();
      var total_pices = order_square_feet / .667;
      tr.find('.pices').val(total_pices);
    })
    $('.pices').keyup(function() {
      var pices = $(this).val();
      var square_feet = pices * .667;
      tr.find('.square_feet').val(square_feet);
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div style="max-width: 60%; margin: 0 auto">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Information</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Square Feet</th>
        <th>Pices</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="invoice_item" class='table'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control pid" name="" id="grade_id">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Product Code - 1001</option>
            <option value="2">Product Code - 1002</option>
            <option value="3">Product Code - 1003</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name='stock' class='form-control stock' value='250'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='square_feet' class='form-control square_feet'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='prices' class='form-control pices'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='sale_price' class='form-control sale_price'></td>
        <td>BDT:<span class='amt'>0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button id="add" type="button" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="remove" type="button" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your code.

1. I did not understand why you put all the event assignments inside `change` event for the dropdown. This will assign multiple keyup events on the same textbox.
2. I put separate `delegate` events for all the textboxes outside the change event for the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var category = $("#grade_id").val();
    //alert(category)
    if (category == '') {
      alert('Please Select Grade');
    } else {
      addNewRow();
    }
  })

  function addNewRow() {

    $("#invoice_item").append('<tr><td><select class="form-control pid" name="" id="grade_id"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">Product Code - 1001</option><option value="2">Product Code - 1002</option><option value="3">Product Code - 1003</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control stock" value="250"></td><td><input type="text" name="square_feet" class="form-control square_feet" ></td><td><input type="text" name="prices" class="form-control pices"></td><td><input type="text" name="sale_price" class="form-control sale_price"></td><td>BDT:<span class="amt">0</span></td></tr>');
  }
  /* for remove row-*/
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    $("#invoice_item").children("tr:last").remove();
  })

  $("#invoice_item").delegate(".pid", "change", function() {
    var pid = $(this).val();
    //alert(pid)
    $(".overlay").show();
  });

  $("#invoice_item").delegate('.price', 'keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".amt").html($(this).closest('tr').find(".qty").val() * $(this).closest('tr').find(".price").val());
  })

  $("#invoice_item").delegate('.square_feet', 'keyup', function() {
    //alert('ok')
    var order_square_feet = $(this).val();
    var total_pices = order_square_feet / .667;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.pices').val(total_pices);
  })

  $("#invoice_item").delegate('.pices', 'keyup', function() {
    var pices = $(this).val();
    var square_feet = pices * .667;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.square_feet').val(square_feet);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div style="max-width: 60%;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Information</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Square Feet</th>
        <th>Pices</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="invoice_item" class='table'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control pid" name="" id="grade_id">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Product Code - 1001</option>
            <option value="2">Product Code - 1002</option>
            <option value="3">Product Code - 1003</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name='stock' class='form-control stock' value='250'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='square_feet' class='form-control square_feet'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='prices' class='form-control pices'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='sale_price' class='form-control sale_price'></td>
        <td>BDT:<span class='amt'>0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button id="add" type="button" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="remove" type="button" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**
`delegate()` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
You might wanna use `on()` instead of `delegate()` https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: this is example code my real code and Jquery version is working . all data come from server.  that real code is not possible to show. thanks @Jones Joseph

Comment: my real code is not working. because you have separate calculation function from $("#invoice_item").delegate(".pid", "change", function() {
    var pid = $(this).val();
    //alert(pid)
    $(".overlay").show(); // all code have to put after here because .667 value come from server .
  });

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

use `$(this).closest('tr').find('td .square_feet')` `closest` for find its parent `tr`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var category = $("#grade_id").val();
    //alert(category)
    if (category == '') {
      alert('Please Select Grade');
    } else {
      addNewRow();
    }
  })

  function addNewRow() {
    /* 
     var grade = $("#grade_id").val();
     //alert(grade)
     $.ajax({
      url :"{{ route('sale.getBrands')}}",
      method : "GET",
      data : {grade:grade},
      success : function(data){
       //alert(data)
       $("#invoice_item").append(data);
       var n = 0;
       $(".number").each(function(){
        $(this).html(++n);
       })
      }
     })*/
    $("#invoice_item").append('<tr><td><select class="form-control pid" name="" id="grade_id"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">Product Code - 1001</option><option value="2">Product Code - 1002</option><option value="3">Product Code - 1003</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control stock" value="250"></td><td><input type="text" name="square_feet" class="form-control square_feet" ></td><td><input type="text" name="prices" class="form-control pices"></td><td><input type="text" name="sale_price" class="form-control sale_price"></td><td>BDT:<span class="amt">0</span></td></tr>');
  }
  /* for remove row-*/
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    $("#invoice_item").children("tr:last").remove();
  })

  $("#invoice_item").delegate(".pid", "change", function() {
    var pid = $(this).val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var td = $(this).parent();
    //alert(pid)
    $(".overlay").show();

    $('.price').keyup(function() {
      tr.find(".amt").html(tr.find(".qty").val() * tr.find(".price").val());
    })

    $('.square_feet').keyup(function() {
      //alert('ok')
      var order_square_feet = $(this).val();
      var total_pices = order_square_feet / .667;
      tr.find('.pices').val(total_pices);
    })
    $('.pices').keyup(function() {
      var pices = $(this).val();
      var square_feet = pices * .667;

      // alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td .square_feet').val());
      //td.find('.square_feet').val(square_feet);
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td .square_feet').val(square_feet);
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<div style="max-width: 60%; margin: 0 auto">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Information</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Square Feet</th>
        <th>Pices</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="invoice_item" class='table'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control pid" name="" id="grade_id">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Product Code - 1001</option>
            <option value="2">Product Code - 1002</option>
            <option value="3">Product Code - 1003</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name='stock' class='form-control stock' value='250'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='square_feet' class='form-control square_feet'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='prices' class='form-control pices'></td>
        <td><input type="text" name='sale_price' class='form-control sale_price'></td>
        <td>BDT:<span class='amt'>0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button id="add" type="button" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id="remove" type="button" style="width:150px;" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: your  code is not working properly. when i add 2 or more row and check square feet or pieces . problem show when i re-add new row after test previous pieces or square feet.

Comment: if  i change previous square feet  all result is  changing

Comment: its working properly. check you select `product information` for that particular row @Md.AzharulIslam

Comment: please check if i change previous square feet then all pieces are changing but if change pieces all not change.

Comment: so what you need now you code like that thats why its happen. say clearly what you need? @Md.AzharulIslam

Answer (score 0):

**@Jones Joseph**
my real code is. If i use your code into my function it is not working. I am using this code in Laravel 5.6 blade file.

```js
$("#invoice_item").delegate(".pid","change",function()
  {
   var pid = $(this).val();
   var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
   $(".overlay").show();
   $.ajax({
    url :"{{ route('sale.getPriceAndQty')}}",
    method : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    data : {getPriceAndQty:1,id:pid},
    data : {id:pid},
    success : function(data)
    {
     //alert(data["sale_price"])
     tr.find("#tqty").val(data["stock_square_feet"]);
     tr.find(".grade_name").val(data["grade_name"]);
     tr.find(".grade_id").val(data["grade_id"]);
     tr.find(".type_id").val(data["type_id"]);
     tr.find(".code_id").val(data["code_id"]);
     tr.find(".per_square_feet").val(data["per_square_feet"]);
     
     tr.find(".qty").val(1);
     tr.find(".price").val(data["per_price"]);
     tr.find(".amt").html( tr.find(".qty").val() * tr.find(".price").val() );
     //calculate(0,0,0);

     $('.qty').keyup(function(){
      $(".order_pices:last").attr("id","intro_"+data['id']);
      var order_square_feet = $(this).val();
      var total_pices = order_square_feet / data["per_square_feet"];
      tr.find('.order_pices').val(total_pices);
     })
     $('.order_pices').keyup(function(){
      var pices = $(this).val();
      var square_feet = pices * data["per_square_feet"];
      tr.find('.qty').val(square_feet);
     })
    }
   })
  })
    
    
    
 });
```