# Javascript add row and calculate multiple rows from html

Tags: javascript, html

I found the post [Add new row and calculate seperate value from html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198326/add-new-row-and-calculate-seperate-value-from-html-table). This is similar to what I am looking for, but I want to save the sum of it as a variable to use the sum in another formula. How can I achieve this? I have tried so much but have not found a real solution. The result of position 1 is correct, but all others are disregarded
Originally it should look like this.
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJS8K.png)

```js
//Calculate Tip
function calculateTip() {
  var montcost = 500;
  var kamera = document.getElementById("kamera1").value;
  var anzahl = document.getElementById("anzahl1").value;
  var laufzeit = document.getElementById("laufzeit").value;
  var datccost = 30;



  //Calculate tip
  var total = ((montcost + (kamera * anzahl)) / laufzeit) + (datccost);
  //round to two decimal places
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  //next line allows us to always have two digits after decimal point
  total = total.toFixed(0);
  //Display the tip
  document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;

}

//Hide the tip amount on load
//document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
//document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

//click to call function
document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
  calculateTip();

};

function numberingTableRow(){
  $.each($('#numberingTable tbody tr'), function (i, v) {
            $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(i+1);
        });
}

  


var counter = 2;

// Function to increment counter
function addRow() {
  counter += 1;
}
//' + counter +'
$(document).on('click','.btnAddRowTable',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#numberingTable tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td><select id="kamera"><option selected value="0">Kamera auswählen</option><option value="500">Kamera 1</option><option value="600">Kamera 2</option><option value="700">Kamera 3</option><option value="800">Kamera 4</option><option value="900">Kamera 5</option></select></td><td><select id="anzahl"><option selected value="0">Anzahl</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btnDeleteRowTable">Delete</button></td></tr>');
  numberingTableRow();
  addRow();

});

$(document).on('click','.btnDeleteRowTable',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  numberingTableRow();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Javascript Tip Calculator</title>




</head>

<body>

  <div id="calculator">


    <form>

      <table id="numberingTable" class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Kamera</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td> <select id="kamera1">
            <option selected value="0">Choose Model</option>
            <option value="500">Model 1</option>
            <option value="600">Model 2</option>
            <option value="700">Model 3</option>
            <option value="800">Model 4</option>
            <option value="900">Model 5</option>
            </select> </td><td>
              <select id="anzahl1">
              <option selected value="0">Qty</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              </select>
              </td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btnDeleteRowTable">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>

      </table>

      <br/>
      <br/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btnAddRowTable">Add article</button>


                <p>Whitch duration?</p>
                <select id="laufzeit">
                <option value="12">12 Monate</option>
                <option value="18">18 Monate</option>
                <option value="24">24 Monate</option>
                </select>


      </form>



      <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate!</button>


  <!--calculator end-->
  <div id="totalTip">
    <sup>€</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
    <small id="each">Monatlich</small>
  </div></div>
<!--container end-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="tipcalculator.js"></script>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will attempt to answer this, which "sum do you need to be saved as a variable"?

Comment: I would like to sum prices. Please view the picture on top. This is what i need.

Comment: just added the complete working solution for your question, perhaps you will need to take it and improve the logic for some edge cases to make it truly perfect.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, I updated it to also solve your local xampp setup.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to modify your function `calculateTip` so you can give it as a parameter the row number you would need to perform your calculation for and run this function against each row.

Note that you should not have multiple elements that share the same ID.
You will need to refactor your HTML too so that you can find each element via different ID, for example here:

```
  var kamera = document.getElementById("kamera[0]").value;
  var anzahl = document.getElementById("anzahl[0]").value;
```

Finally, you just use the variable that tracks the number of rows and ask your updated `calculateTip` to calculate the sum for each row and gather the final sum within `getTotalSum`.

**UPDATE:**
Full solution below, as promised :)

You should also add some extra logic for calculating prices for cases where there is no selected quality nor model, you should be able to complete these extra checks as a homework hehe...

Cheers!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //Calculate Tip
function calculateTip(id = 0) {
  var montcost = 500;
  var kamera = document.getElementById('kamera['+id+']').value;
  var anzahl = document.getElementById('anzahl['+id+']').value;
  var laufzeit = document.getElementById('laufzeit').value;
  var datccost = 30;

  //Calculate tip
  var total = ((montcost + (kamera * anzahl)) / laufzeit) + (datccost);
  return Math.round(total * 100);
}
function getTotalSum() {
  var totalSum = 0;
  var nbr = getCounter();
  for (var cid = 0; cid <= nbr; cid++) {
   //we add sums as integers to avoid floating point errors
   totalSum += calculateTip(cid);
  }
  //Display the tip
  document.getElementById('totalTip').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('tip').innerHTML = (totalSum / 100).toFixed(2); //the final number is presented as it should be rounded to 2 digits after zero!
}

//Hide the tip amount on load
//document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "none";
//document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

//click to call function
document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
  getTotalSum();
};

function numberingTableRow(){
  $.each($('#numberingTable tbody tr'), function (i, v) {
       $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(i+1);
  });
}

var counter = 0; //we can start counting rows from zero, as we like having fun ;)
// Function to increment counter
function addRow() {
  counter += 1;
}
function removeRow() {
  counter -= 1;
}
function getCounter() {
  return counter;
}
//' + counter +'
$(document).on('click','.btnAddRowTable',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  addRow(); //we increase the counter as we are about to add a new row
  counter = getCounter();
  $('#numberingTable tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td><select id="kamera['+counter+']"><option selected value="0">Kamera auswählen</option><option value="500">Kamera 1</option><option value="600">Kamera 2</option><option value="700">Kamera 3</option><option value="800">Kamera 4</option><option value="900">Kamera 5</option></select></td><td><select id="anzahl['+counter+']"><option selected value="0">Anzahl</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btnDeleteRowTable">Delete</button></td></tr>');
  numberingTableRow();
});

$(document).on('click','.btnDeleteRowTable',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  removeRow();
  numberingTableRow();
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Javascript Tip Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--container start-->
  <div id="calculator">
 <form>
  <table id="numberingTable" class="table table-hover table-sm">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>No</th>
     <th>Kamera</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>
      <select id="kamera[0]">
       <option selected value="0">Choose Model</option>
       <option value="500">Model 1</option>
       <option value="600">Model 2</option>
       <option value="700">Model 3</option>
       <option value="800">Model 4</option>
       <option value="900">Model 5</option>
      </select>
     </td>
     <td>
      <select id="anzahl[0]">
       <option selected value="0">Qty</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="7">7</option>
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="11">11</option>
       <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
     </td>
     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btnDeleteRowTable">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btnAddRowTable">Add article</button>
  <p>Whitch duration?</p>
  <select id="laufzeit">
   <option value="12">12 Months</option>
   <option value="18">18 Months</option>
   <option value="24">24 Months</option>
  </select>
 </form>
 <button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate!</button>
 <div id="totalTip">
  <sup>€</sup><span id="tip">0.00</span>
  <small id="each">Monatlich</small>
 </div>
</div>
<!--container end-->

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tipcalculator.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are a superhero ;) Thanks a lot

Comment: Short question. I am putting this to my local xampp server and it says, "unexpected $ line 52". Why? it worked before. 
//' + counter +'
$(document).on('click','.btnAddRowTable',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();

Comment: Seems like you have not included the jquery library. $ is defined there ;-)

Comment: The order of the scripts are loaded matters, load jquery first, then what you wanted.. plus add your JS within $( document ).ready(function() {

console.log( "ready!" );

});